# Show how union is analogous to logical inclusive OR

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

The problem I am trying to solve is showing that a union between sets represents the same action as an inclusive OR. Here is a picture of the work I have:
[image: my work]

This is my for a class activity and my professor says that it is okay, but that it would be more elegant to show with truth tables. I know what the truth table looks like for inclusive OR but I'm not sure how to show that relates to union because in my head, I think of them as the same. I'm probably overthinking this, but does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: $a\in X\cup Y\iff a\in X\lor a\in Y$

Comment: When you pick randomly one item of a set of thngs coming from two sets , the only thing you can say in case , say,  you close your eyes, is that the thing you have picked belongs to one set OR the other. Since it can be said for whatever object you have picked, il can also be said of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to understanding how inclusive disjunction (your inclusive "or", or $\vee$) is related to union, but let us look from your professor's point of view of truth tables.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets: when is $a$ in the union of $X$ and $Y$, $X\cup Y$? When it is in either $X$ (meaning, it is in $X$ and it is NOT in $Y$), or in $Y$ (again, meaning it is in $Y$ and it is NOT in $X$), or simultaneously in both. When $a$ is not in $X\cup Y$? When is, simultaneously, not in $X$ and not in $Y$.

So, we have four cases to consider:

- $a$ is in $X\cup Y$ if $a$ is in $X$ and $a$ is not in $Y$;
- $a$ is in $X\cup Y$ if $a$ is not in $X$ and $a$ is in $Y$;
- $a$ is in $X\cup Y$ if $a$ is in $X$ and $a$ is in $Y$;
- $a$ is not in $X\cup Y$ if $a$ is not in $X$ and $a$ is not in $Y$.

Now, the truth table for the inclusive disjunction is given by (where $T$ stands for true and $F$ for false)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline
 \vee & T & F \\ \hline
T & T & T \\ \hline
F & T & F \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

This means that, for example, when you have a (inclusive) disjuntion of a true statement (line started with $T$) and a false statement (column started with $F$), you have again a true statement (look at where the line started with $T$ meets the column started with $F$).

Well, if write down the content of your table, what you have is the following:

- A (inclusive) disjunction is true if the first statement is true and the second statement is false;
- A disjunction is true if the first statement is false and the second statement is true;
- A disjunction is true if the first statement is true and the second statement is true;
- A disjunction is false if the first statement is false and the second statement is false.

Finally, if in our previous list you replace

- "$a$ is in $X\cup Y$" by "a disjunction is true";
- "$a$ is not in $X\cup Y$" by "a disjunction is false";
- "$a$ is in $X$" by "the first statement is true";
- "$a$ is not in $X$" by "the first statement is false";
- "$a$ is in $Y$" by "the second statement is true";
- "$a$ is not in $Y$" by "the second statement is false",

you obtain precisely the list extracted from our table, and the equivalence between the two notions becomes more evident!